# Interaction between c++11 std::thread and class friend function

Tags: c++, c++11, friend, stdthread

I'm having trouble understanding a compiler error I'm getting trying to use a function declared as a friend to a class in a c++11 `std::thread` object. I've created a small example to show the issue I'm having. Basically, when the compiler has only seen the `friend` function prototype of `aa`, it throws an undefined symbol error when that function is passed into a thread object. I'm using g++ 4.9.2.

```
//test.cpp
#include <thread>

class A {
public:
  friend void aa(A &p);
  void av(void);
};

void A::av() {
  std::thread t1(aa,std::ref(*this));
}

void aa(A &p) {
  p;
}

int main() {
  A ai;
  ai.av();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler command:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -g -O0 -std=c++11 -lpthread
```

I get the compiler error:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void A::av()’:
test.cpp:12:18: error: ‘aa’ was not declared in this scope
   std::thread t1(aa,std::ref(*this));
```

In the above, if I replace the line

```
std::thread t1(aa,std::ref(*this));
```

with

```
aa(*this);
```

This compiles just fine. Alternatively, if I add another prototype declaration of the function above the definition of `A::av`, like:

```
void aa(A &p);
```

It compiles fine with the thread object declaration.

So why is the compiler objecting when I try to declare the thread object with only the friend prototype?

I realize in this trivial example I could move the declaration of `aa` above the definition of `A::av`, however in practice I would like do something more complex where I have a derived class `B` containing `B::av`, and the definition of `aa` is logically placed in the implementation file of `A`, while the definition of class `A` with the prototype of `aa` is located in a header file included in the definition of class `B`. So is this a compiler bug, or an issue with the way I've declared something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With only an in-class declaration, the friend function is only available via argument-dependent lookup. To specify it by name without calling it, as you do in the definition of `av`, you'll need to declare it in the global namespace beforehand, or move the definition to an earlier point.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Can you recommend a way to avoid defining the function twice in the scenario I described at the end? Basically I have A.cpp, A.hpp, B.cpp B.hpp main.cpp, and I define aa in A.cpp, declare the friend prototype in A.hpp, and want to use it in B.cpp (B is a derived class of A).

Comment: @matth: Declare it in the namespace, as well as the class, in `A.hpp`.

Comment: ...or pass a lambda to `std::thread` so ADL works: `std::thread t1{[=]{ aa(*this); }}`.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful.