# Can I use a friend function defined within a class as my thread function?

Tags: c++, c++11, pthreads, friend-function

I'm new to C++ and trying to understand concepts in threads. My reading material surrounding this question is "Anthony Williams - C++ Concurrency in Action" - Listing 3.6.

I have written the listing by myself, but can't seems to get the code to work. I believe the problem I'm facing is calling an in-class `friend` function as the thread function. I have referred to [Interaction between c++11 std::thread and class friend function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498881/) as well.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

class some_big_object
{
};
void swap(some_big_object &lhs, some_big_object &rhs);

class X
{
private:
    some_big_object some_detail;
    std::mutex m;

public:
    X(some_big_object const &sd) : some_detail(sd) {}
    friend void swap(X &lhs, X &rhs)
    {
        if (&lhs == &rhs)
        {
            return;
        }
        std::lock(lhs.m, rhs.m);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_a(lhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock_b(rhs.m, std::adopt_lock);
        swap(lhs.some_detail, rhs.some_detail);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    some_big_object s1;
    some_big_object s2;
    X a(s1);
    X b(s2);
    std::thread t1(swap(a, b));
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error:

[image]

I have tried referring to [Interaction between c++11 std::thread and class friend function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498881/), and a couple of other materials in Tutorials Point and GeekforGeeks.

Comment: I deleted my answer for now, because it needs a complete rehaul. Can you please clarify if it is intentional that you have two `swap`s ? One is `void swap(some_big_object &lhs, some_big_object &rhs)` the other is `void swap(X &lhs, X &rhs)`. Is this correct? Or do you actually want only `void swap(X &lhs, X &rhs)` ?

Comment: I want    void swap(X &lhs, X &rhs) to work, you can skip the declaration    void swap(some_big_object &lhs, some_big_object &rhs);

Comment: it cannot be "skipped" because its part of the issue. So you confirm that there are two overloads and the one you want to call is `void swap(X &lhs, X &rhs)`, correct?

Comment: yes correct, when I said skip what I meant was I tried completely removing ```void swap(some_big_object &lhs, some_big_object &rhs)``` to make things simple, when I remove that and try to compile the compiler still complains that it can't find a matching constructor ```error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::reference_wrapper<X>, std::reference_wrapper<X>)'```. But to answer your question yes these are two overload functions.